# KVM boot from an iso?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, iso, slackware

I'm having trouble with a hosting company that can't seem to install a slackware-13.1.iso image O.o

I'm not sure if they're just trying to fool me around or it's really possible.

I would appreciate if someone can tell a workaround or something like that (if it's possible) :)

Thanks in advance,
The Devil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These are the instructions](http://blog.liw.fi/posts/kvm-for-ubuntu-iso-testing/) for use with the Ubuntu ISOs. It looks like KVM has to be started with special options for the cdrom, then once the installation is complete, it has to be stopped then restarted normally.

Did the host tell you that it wasn't possible at all, or perhaps there's a problem with the ISO that makes it unbootable?  Did you have them check the md5sum of the image?

Comment: They kind of refuse to give me much details. I think they're just to lazy to make things work. They're suggesting me Ubuntu/Debian/Gentoo which doesn't satisfy my needs. What they say is they need an xen image to be able to install it. 
However this hosting is related with a client I'm working for and I can't change the hosting |-(

Comment: My guess is that they want you to provide a pre-installed image rather than them sitting around and installing Linux for you.

Comment: Yes... as I thought... :) 
Thank you for the feedback! I'm not able to add points currently but I'll add you as soon as I can :)